# Partial in rails 3 application renders :per_page times while using will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I am using will_paginate in my rails 3 application.

In my Controller i have a line as

```
def index
  @blogs = Blog.paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[page])
end
```

And in my index.html.erb

```
<div>
  <% if @blogs.size.zero? %>
    No Blogs Found
  <% else %>
    <%= render @blogs if @blogs %> 
  <% end %>
</div>
<%= will_paginate @blogs%>
```

And in my partial _blog.html.erb

```
<% @blogs.each do |blog| %>
  <%= link_to blog.title, blog_path(blog.id)%>
<% end %>
```

When i run the app by $rails s

The partial displays the contents per_page times.. 
 For the first page it displays for 5 times ..

How to avoid so .. 
Give me some suggestions...

```
  EDIT
```

I changed the partial code in _blog.html.erb to
          <%= link_to blog.title, blog_path(blog.id)%>
  which is the right one as already by default rails 3 will send the collection @blogs to the partial noneed for the loop in the partials ..

Answer (score 0):

When render is passed a collection, it automatically renders the partial multiple times.

Therefore you want your partial _blog.html.erb to just be:

```
<%= link_to blog.title, blog_path(blog.id)%>
```

You don't need an each statement there because the render statement takes care of this.

See 3.4.5 "Rendering Collections" in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html